# Browser not showing the SaveAs Dialog even after setting the Content-Disposition in response header

Tags: html, spring, jscript, content-disposition

After reading several queries asked regarding setting Content-Disposition, I finally wrote the below code for sending a file such that Browser shows SaveAs dialog box. However, the Browser doesn't provide with the SaveAs dialog despite setting the "Content-Disposition" in the response header. I could see from the Browser's debug window the file's content and the response header does contain the "Content-Disposition". 
I am clueless as to why the Browser is unable to show the SaveAs popup. Am I missing something here ?

Code:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="...", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
   @ResponseBody
   public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,..) {
   ...

   response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

// set headers for the response
String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
        file.getName());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);

// set content length
response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();

inputStream.close();
    ...
 }
```

The response header when checked from Google Chrome's debug window:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="ABCDEF.abc"
Content-Length:732
Content-Type:application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 04 Jun 2014 19:05:37 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

The html tag for downloading the file:

```
    <div class="divCsvReportIcon">
        <a  class="a-csvReport" href="" target="#"
            data-ng-click="fetchCSVData($event)" ng-show="pivotTabContentShow">
            <img class="csv-img-icon" src="assets/icons/icon_csv-32.png" >
        </a>
    </div>
```

Other Info: 
Spring 3.2.x
Angularjs based html client

Comment: I expect there is some javascript involved to interpret/act upon the data-ng-click? Make sure the javascript does "return false" so as to disable/interrupt the "native" behavior of the <a> tag, which is to link to the current page again (href="").

Comment: I am new to angularjs as well. I tried some sample code to post the get request. Could you pls. help me here on how to handle the response back from $http() method ?

Comment: Below is the request post that I am using, what or how should I handle the response ?

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: srcURI,
                    cache: false
                }) ;